# AutoHotKey KeyWait statements

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using AutoHotKey and I want to achieve something particular.

I have an hotkey that should perform a certain action, inside this hotkey, I would like to code something to detect if I only press the "C" key, or if I press "C" then "L" keys.

If there is only the "C" key pressed, then it should perform an action, otherwise , if "C" then "L" keys are pressed it should do another action.

But I can't do this as I don't really understand KeyWait, I mean how can I do something like that :

```
if(KeyWait, C){
   firstAction
else {
if(KeyWait, C){
  if(KeyWait, L){
  anotherAction
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved using the [input](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm) function.

```
; Get one character and store it in the Character variable
Input, Character, L1
If Character = C
{
    ; Give up to half of one second to type L
    Input, Character, L1 T0.5
    If Character = L
        MsgBox % "We have C and L"
    else
        MsgBox % "Just C here, give an L next time"
}
```